For a connected reductive group G, Ker(Ad_G) = Z(G).
In the text Linear Algebraic Groups and Finite Groups of Lie Type by Gunter Malle and Donna Testerman, the title above is given as an exercise.  I am trying to prepare for an examination that will cover problems throughout the first part of the text.  A hint for this problem is given below:
Hint: By Exercise 10.28 we have Z(G) ≤ ker(Ad). If ker(Ad) is finite, use Exercise 10.4.
For G semisimple, apply Theorem 8.17 to see that a maximal torus
of any simple factor Gi of G acts non-trivially on some root space in g. For the
general case, R(G) = $Z(G)^◦$ ≤ ker(Ad), and Ad induces the adjoint representation of G/R(G) with kernel Z(G/R(G)). Since G/R(G) is semisimple, we have
$Z(G/R(G))^◦$ = 1.
For the general case, how does the fact that $Z(G/R(G))^◦ = 1$ help us?
Thank you for any help.

Here's a MathJax tutorial :)
